# Excel Cell formatting recall

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to enter new data into an excel cell, but still have the cell remember the previous entry?
i.e Cell A1 was 100K, now I enter 80K. But need to know what the prior entry on the cell was???

Comment: Press <escape> or <ctrl>+<z> to restore the previous value in the cell.

Comment: There can only be one value in a cell at a time.  You can "backstep" to the previous value instead of the current one (like DavidPostill's comment), but you can't have a current value and recall the previous one to use in a formula (like current value minus previous value), at least without getting fancy with VBA.  If you need old and new values, put them in seperate cells.

Answer (score 2):

Have not thought this through, but, using:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

is a start. You can save the cell data to a hidden sheet (same location), to recall, put a 'special' code in the cell to copy data from the hidden sheet.